# Folder mapped to user account

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

While setting up TFS for another user, I entered my credentials to connect to the server temporarily.  Well, it still refers to my user name for the working folder.  I even logged in on his machine and removed the workspace reference, but it's still giving him errors that I already mapped the folder to my account name for that project.  How can I remove that mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log on as yourself and delete the workspace.  Or, have him create a new workspace mapped to a new directory.  Workspaces are very flexible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TFS Sidekicks of Attrice to delete the workspace.

http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/index.htm